# Trying to export email body in excel

Tags: python, win32com

I have a list of email that I would like to export the subjects and the body information to take other actions with it. I've been able to extract the subject however the body stays empty.

I would like to see the body and understand how I could input this into an excel file.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = 
win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Mystatsonline")


messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetFirst()

while message:
  print(message.Subject)
  print(message.Body)
  message = messages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine so you must have some kind of antivirus software blocking access to the email bodies. You probably have to disable the email module or the whole antivirus first (but proceed at your own risk!), else migrate the data to an offline or virtual machine with no antivirus.

To get the list of subjects and bodies in Excel format, use a `list of tuples` and write it to a csv file using the `csv` module:

```
import win32com.client
import csv

msglst = [('Subject', 'Body')]   # initialize the list and set the headers

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Mystatsonline")
messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetFirst()

while message:
  msglst.append((message.Subject, message.Body))   # append each subject/body pair to the list
  message = messages.GetNext()

with open('messages_list.csv','w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    wrt = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    wrt.writerows(msglst)   # write each subject/body pair as a new line of the csv file
```

Comment: awesome thank you so much! I had to add an encoding utf-8 and it worked perfectly.
    with open('messages_lists.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8)' as f

Comment: You're welcome. For completeness I've updated my answer with the 'utf-8' encoding parameter you've mentioned